# c++, monitor a directory for changes in windows - _tsplitpath_s was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to build a `c++` program to monitor a directory for changes the files inside it. The [Obtaining Directory Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/obtaining-directory-change-notifications) is recommended in many questions similar to mine. I tried that code but the first error is

> _tsplitpath_s was not declared in this scope

the error belongs to the line

```
_tsplitpath_s(lpDir, lpDrive, 4, NULL, 0, lpFile, _MAX_FNAME, lpExt, _MAX_EXT);
```

I use `gcc version 5.1.0` and run the code by the following command in CMD

`g++ file.cpp -o out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code uses a Microsoft-specific extension to the *stdlib.h* implementation. [_splitpath_s and _wsplitpath_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-s-wsplitpath-s) are only available, when using the *stdlib.h* implementation that ships with Microsoft's compiler. It is not available in the *stdlib.h* implementation that comes with GCC.

To work around this, you can either use the Standard C++ [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (may not be [immediately available with your compiler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)), or provide your own implementation of the `splitpath` functionality.

Alternatively, don't call `_tsplitpath_s` at all, and make sure to always pass a directory and drive name to `WatchDirectory` in the sample code.

Comment: Thank you. Do you recommend QFileSystemWatcher to do this task?

Comment: @noo: The question is tagged [tag:c++] and [tag:winapi]. `QFileSystemWatcher` is part of Qt. Qt is not part of C++ or the Windows API. If you are fine with using Qt, then go ahead and use what works for you. Personally, I wouldn't recommend using Qt for *anything*, but that's just me.

Comment: I am new to this thing, and I really don't know where to find my solution

Comment: @noo: You already *have* the solution. You just don't know the basics to make it work for you. Head over to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329), and plan to invest a few years, until you have a solid foundation on which to expand.

Comment: While your answer is correct for gcc 5.1, it makes it sound as `filesystem` is not in the standard yet. As of C++17 there is [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Comment: I ran that code by Visual Studio 2017 and it gave me no error

Comment: @noo: Yes. Of course. This being a Microsoft-specific extension it is available when using Microsoft's compiler together with Microsoft's support libraries (like *stdlib.h*).

Comment: The `argc` is not equal to `2`. How can I send directory as parameter to `argv`?

Comment: @noo: Get a few books from the list I posted above. They will answer all of those questions.

Answer (score 1):

To start, make sure you've got `<stdlib.h>` included.

My psychic powers suggest it's a legacy `tchar.h` thing.  In this day and age, try to avoid using the "t" apis and use the Unicode ones specifically:

If `lpDir`, `lpDrive` and other parameters are an ansi strings (char*):

```
_splitpath_s(lpDir, lpDrive, 4, NULL, 0, lpFile, _MAX_FNAME, lpExt, _MAX_EXT);
```

If they are unicode (WCHAR*, wchar_t*, LPCWSTR, etc...):

```
_wsplitpath_s(lpDir, lpDrive, 4, NULL, 0, lpFile, _MAX_FNAME, lpExt, _MAX_EXT);
```

Comment: That's not going to help. [_splitpath_s, _wsplitpath_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-s-wsplitpath-s) are Microsoft-specific extensions, not available in a conforming *stdlib.h* implementation other than Microsoft's. The clue here is the leading underscore (`_`), moving the symbol into the namespace reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: True. Avoiding the `TCHAR`-based functions remains as a good advise though!